# Modifying a custom style file to get smaller margins

Tags: formatting, margins

I'm using the `res.cls` style file with a `.tex` file based on `res2.tex` [available here](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/).

I'm trying to get smaller left and right margins to be able to change the font size to 11pt so it scales nicely without creating an unreadable mess. I added these before `\begin{document}`:

```
% Modifications to res
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.75cm} % smaller vertical space at the top
\setlength{\sectionskip}{1cm} % bigger vertical space between sections
\setlength{\hoffset}{2cm}     % smaller left margin
\textwidth=6.0in              % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin
```

The first two `\setlength{}` are fine. However, the last two lines only affect the actual sections (Education, etc.), not the `\address{}` part (which is inside `\begin{document}` but before `\begin{resume}`).

I would like to get the `\address{}` part with `\name{}` aligned with the sections (Education, etc.) on the left (and the right).

I've spent a bunch of time looking at the `.cls` file trying to understand what's happening and what I should modify, but it leads nowhere. I've also tried the `geometry` package, but to no avail.

[image: screenshot of my output]

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I could do a "workaround." I simply added `\hspace{-1.45cm}` before each line of the first `\address{}` (the one that appears on the left), like this:

```
\address{\hspace{-1.45cm} FirstLineOfAddress \\ \hspace{-1.45cm} SecondLineOfAddress}
```

The `-1.45cm` value is arbitrary but it looks okay. For `\name{}` at the top, I used half of the value (`-0.725cm`) since the name is supposed to be centered.

I don't know how I didn't think of this sooner.

Comment: The question was worth asking, since it reveals a problem often seen by LaTeX users: Some things are hard to customize without work-arounds.